# On the derivation of the north-south aberration angle

Tags: optics, astronomy, telescopes

In A.P. French's *Special relativity*, page [$39$](https://books.google.com/books?id=8jPVRXNXj28C&pg=PA40&lpg=PA40&dq=north+south+component+aberration&source=bl&ots=vOmmcnGx1l&sig=ACfU3U0Lms2ttIcQs0jfBjCeCjbBk8iUhA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi_0NrKyuzmAhVjMX0KHYTVDsIQ6AEwCXoECAkQAQ#v=onepage&q&f=false), the author said the north-south aberration angle $\alpha$ below, in figure (b), is equal to $v\sin(\theta_{0})/{c}$, where $\theta_{0}$ is the angle when the earth is stationary (no aberration).

[image]

How did $v\sin(\theta_{0})/c$ came about?

This value seems rather suspicious, especially because of the $\sin(\theta_{0})$. According to [this](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Aberration_(astronomy)#/Bradley%27s_classical_explanation) Wikipedia article, the angle $\theta$ above (named $\phi$ in the article) satisfies $$\tan(\theta)=\frac { \sin(\theta_{0})}{v/c +  \cos (\theta_{0})},$$

thus,

$$\tan(\alpha)=\tan(\theta_{0}-\theta)=\frac{\frac{\sin(\theta_{0})}{\cos(\theta_{0})}-\frac { \sin(\theta_{0})}{v/c +  \cos (\theta_{0})}}{1+\frac{\sin(\theta_{0})}{\cos(\theta_{0})}\times \frac { \sin(\theta_{0})}{v/c +  \cos (\theta_{0})}}.$$

I highly doubt that taking the $\tan^{-1}$ of the above would result in $v\sin(\theta_{0})/c$.

Is there a simpler way to compute the aberration angle to check whether it conforms with $v\sin(\theta_{0})/c$?

Comment: My guess is that the expression is actually $\sin\alpha=(v\sin\theta_0)/c$ (which you can verify using fig. (b) and some trig), then assuming small $\alpha$ to approximate $\sin\alpha\approx \alpha$.

Comment: @hiccups That must be some heavy trig, I've been trying for a while with no success. We essentially have two equalities $sin(\theta_{0})=\sin(\alpha+\theta)=\sin(\alpha)\cos(\theta)+\sin(\theta)\cos(\alpha)$, and $\sin(\theta)/ \cos(\theta)=c/v$. We need another equation relating $\sin(\theta)$ and $\cos(\theta)$ in order to get rid of $\theta$ in the very first equation, i.e., $\sin(\theta_{0})=\sin(\alpha)\cos(\theta)+\sin(\theta)\cos(\alpha)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use 4-vectors (with $c\equiv 1$):

$$ k_{\mu} = (\omega, k_x, k_y, k_z) = k(1, -\cos{\theta_0}, -\sin{\theta_0}, 0) $$

is the wave-vector in the stationary frame. The angle of arrival is given by

$$\theta = \tan^{-1}{\frac{k_y}{k_x}}=\tan^{-1}{\frac{-\sin\theta_0}{-\cos\theta_0}}=\theta_0$$

Boost by $v$:

$$ k'_{\mu} = (\gamma(\omega-vk_x), \gamma(k_x-\omega v), k_y, k_z) $$

$$ k'_{\mu} = k(\gamma(1+v\cos\theta_0), -\gamma(\cos\theta_0+v), -\sin\theta_0, 0) $$

so:

$$\theta' = \tan^{-1}{\frac{k'_y}{k'_x}}=\tan^{-1}{\frac{\sin\theta_0}{\gamma(\cos\theta_0+v)}}$$

which reduced to the wiki expression at solar system velocities ($\gamma < 1+10^{-8}$).

Note: I once did this with aerospace engineers trying to point a star tracker in deep space. They were taking a 3+1 approach and were in knots.  They down right thought it was physicists' voodoo.

So now that we have a rigorous expression, we need to consider the fact that $v \ll c$ and that $\alpha \ll 1$. That means two things (with $\gamma \approx 1$):

$$ \tan{\theta} = \frac{\sin\theta_0}{\cos\theta_0 +v}=\frac{\tan\theta_0}{1+v/\cos{\theta_0}}\approx \tan\theta_0[1-v/\cos\theta_0]$$

Meanwhile, a Taylor expansion about $\theta_0$ gives:

$$ \tan\theta \equiv \tan{(\theta_0-\alpha)} \approx \tan\theta_0 - \alpha\cdot[\tan x]'_{|x=\theta_0}=\tan\theta_0 - \alpha/\cos^2{\theta_0}$$
$$ \tan\theta = \tan\theta_0[1 - \frac{\alpha}{\cos\theta_0\sin\theta_0}]$$

Setting:

$$ \frac v{\cos\theta_0} = \frac{\alpha}{\cos\theta_0\sin\theta_0}$$

and reintroducing $c$ gives:

$$\alpha = \frac v c \sin\theta_0$$

Comment: I really do appreciate the effort, and this method indeed is very efficient at finding the east-west aberration angle. But the question was not really about the derivation of the wiki expression; rather, it's about the one that figured in French's book, i.e., $v\sin(\theta_{0})/c$, the north-south aberration angle. Note that you can check the page in the book by clicking on the page number in my post.

Comment: OK. will edit with small angle approximations.

Comment: btw: I have no idea what N/S vs. E/W aberration angle means. There is basically longitudinal and transverse defined in the problem.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

If you construct the right-angle triangle as shown in red on fig. (b) then it is easy to see that $\sin\alpha = \text{something}/c$. And by breaking $v$ into components you can see (from the doodle on the right) that the something is equal to $v\sin\theta_0$.

Then, as mentioned in my comment, all that's left is to say that $\alpha$ is small (i.e. $v\ll c$) so that $(v\sin\theta_0) /c=\sin\alpha\approx\alpha$.

(Please excuse the shoddy MS Paint editing.)